# Wrong result of my code

Tags: java, java-io

I read Thinking in Java. I am reading chapter I/O.
According to the book, then I read the file "CADState.out" after serialization, it cannot be read correctly. 
Because Bruce Eckel says : "It’s as if the statics didn’t get serialized at all! ... So if you want to serialize statics, you must do it yourself."

I have tested this code in my computer many times, but it serialize properly.

Maybe anyone can help me?

(My computer - Java Version 7 Update 67, Mac OS X 10.9.4)

```
package IO;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random; 

abstract class Shape implements Serializable {
    public static final int RED = 1, BLUE = 2, GREEN = 3;
    private int xPos, yPos, dimension;
    private static Random rand = new Random(47);
    private static int counter = 0;
    public abstract void setColor(int newColor);
    public abstract int getColor();
    public Shape(int xVal, int yVal, int dim) {
        xPos = xVal;
        yPos = yVal;
        dimension = dim;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return getClass() +
                "color[" + getColor() + "] xPos[" + xPos +
                "] yPos[" + yPos + "] dim[" + dimension + "]\n";
    }
    public static Shape randomFactory() {
        int xVal = rand.nextInt(100);
        int yVal = rand.nextInt(100);
        int dim = rand.nextInt(100);
        switch(counter++ % 3) {
        default:
        case 0: return new Circle(xVal, yVal, dim);
        case 1: return new Square(xVal, yVal, dim);
        case 2: return new Line(xVal, yVal, dim);
        } 
    }
}
class Circle extends Shape {
    private static int color = RED;
    public Circle(int xVal, int yVal, int dim) {
        super(xVal, yVal, dim);
    }
    public void setColor(int newColor) { color = newColor; }
    public int getColor() { return color; }
}
class Square extends Shape {
    private static int color;
    public Square(int xVal, int yVal, int dim) {
        super(xVal, yVal, dim);
        color = RED; 
    }
    public void setColor(int newColor) { color = newColor; }
    public int getColor() { return color; }
}
class Line extends Shape {
    private static int color = RED;
    public static void
    serializeStaticState(ObjectOutputStream os)
            throws IOException { os.writeInt(color); }
    public static void
    deserializeStaticState(ObjectInputStream os)
            throws IOException { color = os.readInt(); }
    public Line(int xVal, int yVal, int dim) {
        super(xVal, yVal, dim);
    }
    public void setColor(int newColor) { color = newColor; }
    public int getColor() { return color; }
}

public class Thirty {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        List<Class<? extends Shape>> shapeTypes =
                new ArrayList<Class<? extends Shape>>();
        // Add references to the class objects:
        shapeTypes.add(Circle.class);
        shapeTypes.add(Square.class);
        shapeTypes.add(Line.class);
        List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        // Make some shapes:
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            shapes.add(Shape.randomFactory());
        // Set all the static colors to GREEN:
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            ((Shape)shapes.get(i)).setColor(Shape.GREEN);
        // Save the state vector:
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream("CADState.out"));
        out.writeObject(shapeTypes);
        Line.serializeStaticState(out);
        out.writeObject(shapes);
        // Display the shapes:
        System.out.println(shapes);


        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("CADState.out"));
        // Read in the same order they were written:
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Class<? extends Shape>> shapeTypes2 = (List<Class<? extends Shape>>)in.readObject();
        Line.deserializeStaticState(in);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Shape> shapes2 = (List<Shape>)in.readObject();
        System.out.println(shapes2);

    }

}
```

Output of this code according to the book:

```
[class Circlecolor[3] xPos[58] yPos[55] dim[93]
, class Squarecolor[3] xPos[61] yPos[61] dim[29]
, class Linecolor[3] xPos[68] yPos[0] dim[22]
, class Circlecolor[3] xPos[7] yPos[88] dim[28]
, class Squarecolor[3] xPos[51] yPos[89] dim[9]
, class Linecolor[3] xPos[78] yPos[98] dim[61]
, class Circlecolor[3] xPos[20] yPos[58] dim[16]
, class Squarecolor[3] xPos[40] yPos[11] dim[22]
, class Linecolor[3] xPos[4] yPos[83] dim[6]
, class Circlecolor[3] xPos[75] yPos[10] dim[42]
]
[class Circlecolor[1] xPos[58] yPos[55] dim[93]
, class Squarecolor[0] xPos[61] yPos[61] dim[29]
, class Linecolor[3] xPos[68] yPos[0] dim[22]
, class Circlecolor[1] xPos[7] yPos[88] dim[28]
, class Squarecolor[0] xPos[51] yPos[89] dim[9]
, class Linecolor[3] xPos[78] yPos[98] dim[61]
, class Circlecolor[1] xPos[20] yPos[58] dim[16]
, class Squarecolor[0] xPos[40] yPos[11] dim[22]
, class Linecolor[3] xPos[4] yPos[83] dim[6]
, class Circlecolor[1] xPos[75] yPos[10] dim[42]
```

Output this code on my computer:

```
[class IO.Circlecolor[3] xPos[58] yPos[55] dim[93]
, class IO.Squarecolor[3] xPos[61] yPos[61] dim[29]
, class IO.Linecolor[3] xPos[68] yPos[0] dim[22]
, class IO.Circlecolor[3] xPos[7] yPos[88] dim[28]
, class IO.Squarecolor[3] xPos[51] yPos[89] dim[9]
, class IO.Linecolor[3] xPos[78] yPos[98] dim[61]
, class IO.Circlecolor[3] xPos[20] yPos[58] dim[16]
, class IO.Squarecolor[3] xPos[40] yPos[11] dim[22]
, class IO.Linecolor[3] xPos[4] yPos[83] dim[6]
, class IO.Circlecolor[3] xPos[75] yPos[10] dim[42]
]
[class IO.Circlecolor[3] xPos[58] yPos[55] dim[93]
, class IO.Squarecolor[3] xPos[61] yPos[61] dim[29]
, class IO.Linecolor[3] xPos[68] yPos[0] dim[22]
, class IO.Circlecolor[3] xPos[7] yPos[88] dim[28]
, class IO.Squarecolor[3] xPos[51] yPos[89] dim[9]
, class IO.Linecolor[3] xPos[78] yPos[98] dim[61]
, class IO.Circlecolor[3] xPos[20] yPos[58] dim[16]
, class IO.Squarecolor[3] xPos[40] yPos[11] dim[22]
, class IO.Linecolor[3] xPos[4] yPos[83] dim[6]
, class IO.Circlecolor[3] xPos[75] yPos[10] dim[42]
]
```

Comment: What version of Java are you running, and what version of Java is the book written against?

Comment: Java Version 7 Update 67, Mac OS X 10.9.4

Comment: Java only serializes non transient, non static fields. Static fields belong to the class itself, not the instance; so it wouldn't make much sense to serialize it. Do you want the static fields to be serialized?

Comment: I just want to get the same result as in the book, if it possible.

Comment: Try commenting out `((Shape)shapes.get(i)).setColor(Shape.GREEN);` you're setting every color to green.

Comment: I understood that ) But in the book this part of code without comment. They said that static fields will not be serialize if you use "implements Serializable". And after it author offers the solution. But in my code it's completely vise versa. The bottom line is the author sets this parts in green color, and after reading "CADState.out" the color became not green.

Comment: The solution is remove the `static` keyword from the fields you'd like to be serialized, making them a "per object" variable instead of a "class global". Java will then happily serialize your variable, and it will deserialize  with all of its needed information.

Comment: The only difference I can see between your output and the book's is that the class names are different because yours are all in package `IO`.

Comment: Not only this, also number of the color.

Comment: Very strange wording by Bruce Eckel. The statics *don't* get serialized. No 'as if' about it. Assuming you've quoted it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my mistake. Thanks those guys - http://www.coderanch.com/t/546558/java-io/java/Serialization-static-variables. 
Rob Spoor : Variable y is static. That means that as long as the class is loaded, it will keep the same value. You are serializing and de-serializing inside the same JVM instance. Try splitting the serialization and de-serialization into two classes and see the difference.

And I have split the code into two classes: Thirty and ThirtyRead. After that, everything start to work properly. Frankly, in the book it was two classes too )). But, I haven't noticed it. I put everything in the same class.

Here solution. Class Thirty:

```
package IO;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random; 

abstract class Shape implements Serializable {
    public static final int RED = 1, BLUE = 2, GREEN = 3;
    private int xPos, yPos, dimension;
    private static Random rand = new Random(47);
    private static int counter = 0;
    public abstract void setColor(int newColor);
    public abstract int getColor();
    public Shape(int xVal, int yVal, int dim) {
        xPos = xVal;
        yPos = yVal;
        dimension = dim;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return getClass() +
                "color[" + getColor() + "] xPos[" + xPos +
                "] yPos[" + yPos + "] dim[" + dimension + "]\n";
    }
    public static Shape randomFactory() {
        int xVal = rand.nextInt(100);
        int yVal = rand.nextInt(100);
        int dim = rand.nextInt(100);
        switch(counter++ % 3) {
        default:
        case 0: return new Circle(xVal, yVal, dim);
        case 1: return new Square(xVal, yVal, dim);
        case 2: return new Line(xVal, yVal, dim);
        } 
    }
}
class Circle extends Shape {
    private static int color = RED;
    public Circle(int xVal, int yVal, int dim) {
        super(xVal, yVal, dim);
    }
    public void setColor(int newColor) { color = newColor; }
    public int getColor() { return color; }
}
class Square extends Shape {
    private static int color;
    public Square(int xVal, int yVal, int dim) {
        super(xVal, yVal, dim);
        color = RED; 
    }
    public void setColor(int newColor) { color = newColor; }
    public int getColor() { return color; }
}
class Line extends Shape {
    private static int color = RED;
    public static void
    serializeStaticState(ObjectOutputStream os)
            throws IOException { os.writeInt(color); }
    public static void
    deserializeStaticState(ObjectInputStream os)
            throws IOException { color = os.readInt(); }
    public Line(int xVal, int yVal, int dim) {
        super(xVal, yVal, dim);
    }
    public void setColor(int newColor) { color = newColor; }
    public int getColor() { return color; }
}

public class Thirty {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        List<Class<? extends Shape>> shapeTypes =
                new ArrayList<Class<? extends Shape>>();
        // Add references to the class objects:
        shapeTypes.add(Circle.class);
        shapeTypes.add(Square.class);
        shapeTypes.add(Line.class);
        List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        // Make some shapes:
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            shapes.add(Shape.randomFactory());
        // Set all the static colors to GREEN:
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            ((Shape)shapes.get(i)).setColor(Shape.GREEN);
        // Save the state vector:
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream("CADState.out"));
        out.writeObject(shapeTypes);
        Line.serializeStaticState(out);
        out.writeObject(shapes);
        // Display the shapes:
        System.out.println(shapes);

    }

}

// output
[class IO.Circlecolor[3] xPos[58] yPos[55] dim[93]
, class IO.Squarecolor[3] xPos[61] yPos[61] dim[29]
, class IO.Linecolor[3] xPos[68] yPos[0] dim[22]
, class IO.Circlecolor[3] xPos[7] yPos[88] dim[28]
, class IO.Squarecolor[3] xPos[51] yPos[89] dim[9]
, class IO.Linecolor[3] xPos[78] yPos[98] dim[61]
, class IO.Circlecolor[3] xPos[20] yPos[58] dim[16]
, class IO.Squarecolor[3] xPos[40] yPos[11] dim[22]
, class IO.Linecolor[3] xPos[4] yPos[83] dim[6]
, class IO.Circlecolor[3] xPos[75] yPos[10] dim[42]
]
```

Class ThirtyRead

```
    package IO;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ThirtyRead {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("CADState.out"));
            // Read in the same order they were written:
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Class<? extends Shape>> shapeTypes2 = (List<Class<? extends Shape>>)in.readObject();
            Line.deserializeStaticState(in);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Shape> shapes2 = (List<Shape>)in.readObject();
            System.out.println(shapes2);

        }

    }
// output

    [class IO.Circlecolor[1] xPos[58] yPos[55] dim[93]
    , class IO.Squarecolor[0] xPos[61] yPos[61] dim[29]
    , class IO.Linecolor[3] xPos[68] yPos[0] dim[22]
    , class IO.Circlecolor[1] xPos[7] yPos[88] dim[28]
    , class IO.Squarecolor[0] xPos[51] yPos[89] dim[9]
    , class IO.Linecolor[3] xPos[78] yPos[98] dim[61]
    , class IO.Circlecolor[1] xPos[20] yPos[58] dim[16]
    , class IO.Squarecolor[0] xPos[40] yPos[11] dim[22]
    , class IO.Linecolor[3] xPos[4] yPos[83] dim[6]
    , class IO.Circlecolor[1] xPos[75] yPos[10] dim[42]
    ]
```